# Polymer 1.0: Conditional Flow statements

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Can I do something like the following, in Polymer 1.0:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
 <template is="dom-if" if="{{ messagetype=='chat' }}">
  <p>{{message.text}}</p>
 </template>
 <template is="dom-if" if="{{ messagetype=='location' }}">
  <p>{{message.latitude}} , {{message.longitude}}</p>
 </template>
</template>
```

i.e make a decision based on `messagetype` binding and write nothing else in `Polymer()` function

Answer (score 1):

Expression syntax in Polymer 1.0 is very limited. 
You can access fields (or propeeties) and functions. 
The expression can use `!` for `not` and `.` for `.` for array index and object property access. 
For everything esle create a function that returns the computed result. 
See also https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#expressions-in-binding-annotations
For your example you could create a function like

```
function: isEqual(a, b) {
  return a == b;
}
```

and use it in the binding like

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{isEqual(messagetype, 'chat')}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good use of dom-if statements. You are better off creating a function that computes what text to put into the p tag and moving the conditional logic into there.

Something along the lines of this:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
    <p>[[computeMessageValue(message, messagetype)]]</p> 
</template>
```

With the following computing function:

```
computeMessageValue: function (message, messagetype) {
    if (messagetype === 'chat') {
        return message.text;
    } else if (messagetype === 'location') {
        return message.latitude + ' , ' + message.longitude;
    }
}
```

Using the dom-if approach is slower, harder to write tests for and gets very messy very quick as you add in new message types.